# How to read data from a file without rounding numbers having more than 16 digits precision?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Numbers with more than 16 digits precision are auto-rounded by default while reading data from a file in Node.js using **readFileSync** method of **fs** module.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(file)
```

**data** contains numbers that are auto-rounded as follows for example:

```
0.91544900000000007 is rounded to 0.9154490000000001

4647.3424257097241 to 4647.342425709725
```

How to read data from file as is without rounding ?

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file, you receive a **string**. Strings can't be rounded.

```
// temp.txt:
9154490000000000723581950185310538193807258123518235015387
```

```
// node:
fs.readFileSync('temp.txt').toString(); // not rounded
```

As for rounding when parsing the string as a float, there's `BigInt` for integers

```
// node:
let str = fs.readFileSync('temp.txt').toString();
let int = BigInt(str);
```

I'm unaware of a similar solution in vanilla node for floats. You can look into npm packages e.g. `BigFloat` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in Javascript comes in two flavors:

1. [Numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754. This is a binary format that occupies 64 bits (8 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 53 bits (about 16 decimal digits).
2. [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), can be used for arbitrarily large integers.

There is no native solution for better precision. Maybe [float80](https://github.com/brianmhunt/float80) could help you, that can read 80-bit Extended Floating Point Numbers from buffers